# How UIViewController interact with Storyboard under the hood

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm new to iOS development and this could be a stupid question for some experienced guys...

When I create a new iOS project in Xcode, I get a `ViewController` class and a storyboard which sets its **Custom Class** to this `ViewController`. It looks like there is a "Storyboard" class holding an instance of `ViewController`, however, I cannot find where this "Storyboard" class is defined.

Even though I know how to create multiple subclasses of `UIViewController` to handle different views interaction following some tutorials, I still find it uncomfortable to associate these subclasses to the storyboard by selecting them in the storyboard panel. I would rather see something like a "Storyboard" class holding an array of `UIViewController`.

So my question is, how these `UIViewController` interact with the Storyboard under the hood?

Thanks

Comment: Apple does document the UIStoryboard class. Have you checked that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly, it happens as follows:

1. App launches.
2. App loads storryboard.
3. Depending on app's navigation structure, app instantiates each view controller inside the storyboard as needed.

The storyboard contains detailed information on:

- Which custom subclass of `UIViewController`, `UINavigtionController`, etc. to use for instantiating each view controller in the storyboard.
- How to map (connect) each if its view controllers' subviews to the corresponding custom classes' outlets and actions.

But seriously, read Apple's docs. It's all there.

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` has a property named `storyboard` which refers to the storyboard file associated with the viewcontroller subclass.
Also the view controller code are interecting with the storyboard with connections symboled with `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction`.